# Segoe font not getting added in google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, fonts, google-visualization

I want to add Segoe UI font to Google Bar Chart. I tried adding it using fontName attribute. But its showing error in Network tab. In console its printing this error:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()**

You can see the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y2fhwvec/).

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarColors);

function drawBarColors() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', '2010 Population', '2000 Population'],
        ['New York City, NY', 8175000, 8008000],
        ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000, 3694000],
        ['Chicago, IL', 2695000, 2896000],
        ['Houston, TX', 2099000, 1953000],
        ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000, 1517000]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
        colors: ['#b0120a', '#ffab91'],
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Total Population',
          minValue: 0
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'City'
        },
        titleTextStyle: { 
  color:'#3a3a3a',
  fontSize:24,
  bold:false,
  fontName: "Segoe UI"
  },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
 }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when I run the above snippet, the Segoe UI font appears fine, and is included inline -- from the title element --> `<text text-anchor="start" x="160" y="27.4" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="24" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#3a3a3a">Population of Largest U.S. Ci…</text>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do it using CSS only. Do let me know in case you want to do it other way.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarColors);

function drawBarColors() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', '2010 Population', '2000 Population'],
        ['New York City, NY', 8175000, 8008000],
        ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000, 3694000],
        ['Chicago, IL', 2695000, 2896000],
        ['Houston, TX', 2099000, 1953000],
        ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000, 1517000]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Population of Largest U.S. Cities',
        chartArea: {width: '50%'},
        colors: ['#b0120a', '#ffab91'],
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Total Population',
          minValue: 0
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'City'
        },
        titleTextStyle: { 
  color:'#3a3a3a',
  fontSize:24,
  bold:false
  },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
 }
```

```css
#chart_div g g text{
    font-family:Segoe UI !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I tried with the above css. But its not working. The <g> tag is coming under some divs and one svg tag.

Comment: What is the issue? It is working fine in my fiddle.

Comment: the issue is in console we can see some error related to the font like Could not find the original style sheet. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the exact error message? Did you try the exact solution as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I removed fontName from chart options and added the css you've provided. But it showed the text in default Arial only.

Comment: Can you update your code snippet? I will look at it to resolve the issue.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

This is the exact message I'm getting in console. Once I click on this error its opening https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Segoe+UI and displaying the following:
Could not find the original style sheet.

Comment: I am getting this error if I try to use `fontName: "Segoe UI"` in chart options. Just remove this line, add CSS from my answer, empty cache and reload to see the result.